# Put quotation marks around every item in a list

Tags: xetex, quotation

This looks like a very simple problem, but I can't find any obvious solution. I am dealing with long lists of quotes, and currently I'm doing it manually:

```
 \begin{itemize}
  \item "1st quote here."
  \item "2nd quote here."
\end{itemize}
```

Manually typing in quotation marks '00s of times gets old fast. Is there a switch I could use for quoting each item of a list in one go?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could create a command that redefines `\item`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\let\olditem\item
\newcommand{\StartQuotation}{%
\def\item{\unskip''\olditem``}``%
}
\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
  \item\StartQuotation 1st quote here.
  \item 2nd quote here.
  \item 3nd quote here.
  \item 4th quote here.''
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

[image]

You still have add `\StartQuotation` and one `''` per list, but not more than that.

Comment: Absolutely perfect! This is exactly what I wanted. Thanks, @Schrödinger'scat!

Comment: @user3671 You're welcome!

Answer (score 7):

An elegant way do this is to use regular expressions from [LaTeX3](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/l3kernel). The idea is to use the `\item` commands to split the contents of the environment after which you can recreate the `itemize` environment with quotation marks around each entry. This way the code:

```
  \begin{qitemize}
    \item 1st quote here.
    \item 2nd quote here.
  \end{qitemize}
```

produces the requested output of:

[image]

The code itself is not that long but if you are not familiar with LaTeX3 and regular expressions then it may look a little cryptic.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\seq_new:N \l_items_seq
\NewDocumentEnvironment{qitemize}{ +b }{
  % split the environment contents around the \item commands
  \regex_split:nnN { \s*\c{item}\s* } { #1 } \l_items_seq
  \seq_pop_left:NN \l_items_seq \l_items_tl % pop empty first item
  \seq_if_empty:NF \l_items_seq { % check for no items
    \begin{itemize}% create the quoted itemize environment
      \seq_map_inline:Nn \l_items_seq { \item ``##1'' }
    \end{itemize}
  }
}{}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

  \begin{qitemize}
    \item 1st quote here.
    \item 2nd quote here.
  \end{qitemize}

\end{document}
```

Above I said that I split the contents of the environment around the `\item` commands but this was a slight lie because the code actually splits around the `\item` command together with the spaces on either side of it, which is why the two `\s*` appear inside the regular expression. This is so that you do not end up quoting the spaces before and after each item.

Finally, note that  the `\item` command in the `qitemize` environment does not correctly cater for an optional argument, such as `\item[*] quoted item`. With a little extra work this would be possible.

Comment: Thanks, @Andrew - I was not aware of LaTeX3. Will definitely look into this.